# each time TortoiseSVN (when connected via VPN) fails first time, but works second time

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, commit, vpn

I am using TortoiseSVN 1.9.3 and VPN connection (Windows 10 64 bits). Each time when I try to do an action (svn checkout, svn update, show log, svn commit) it stays for about 1-2 minutes (I do not wait until the end, I press the Cancel button after around 10-15 seconds normally). Then I try again the exact same action, for example, if it was a commit, I just press again the Commit button (the commit window being opened from the first attempt), and this time it works. If I do another action fast enough, it works from the first time. If I wait and do it later, I have again the issue: first time fails, second time it works.

The error I get if I let it until the end:

```
Commit failed (details follow):
Unable to connect to a repository at URL
 'http://192.168.1.200:83/svn/project/trunk'
Connection timed out
```

I worked on VPN some years ago, on similar conditions (Windows 7 64 bits), so I suppose there was an older version of TortoiseSVN, and I had the same behavior.

This is very frustrating as it takes lots minutes when I need for example to check multiple files.

Do you have any idea why this happen?

Answer (score 2):

Set up a pre-commit hook script in the [settings dialog](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html), and set the `connectVPN.exe` tool as the script.

The reason you get an error on the first connect is that on the first connect, your VPN isn't ready yet.

Comment: Thank you. I added a pre-commit hook, putting in the Working Copy Path the folder where I have the sources locally and in Command Line To Execute: C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\ConnectVPN.exe vpn.servername.ro Unfortunately I get an error when trying to commit: "If the connection is active nothing happens. If the connection is inactive the standard connection dialog will be displayed." and "The hook script returned an error:" I am using Cisco Systems VPN Client 5.0.07. How can I fix this?

Comment: That dialog is shown if the parameters passed to ConnectVPN are not correct. Try putting "vpn.servername.ro" in quotes. And make sure you don't pass any more parameters.

Comment: Sorry, but adding quotes still does not work. I get the same error. I am confused because the parameter of ConnectVPC.exe is "name of the VPN connection". It's not clear what "name" means... the URL, the host name?